# Wordpress - получить url изображения нужного размера по ID записи

Tags: wordpress, изображения

У записи есть миниатюра. 
Размеры миниатюр заданы:

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
    add_image_size( '270_250', 270, 250);
    add_image_size( '170_158', 170, 158);
}
```

Нужно получить изображение размером 170x158 по ID записи.
Использую

```
$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( 43 , array( 170, 158 ) ) );
```

Возвращает url на изображение размером 150х150. Как получить изображение нужного размера?
(соответствующий файл существует)

Спасибо

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте задавать размеры новой миниатюры так:

```
if (function_exists('add_image_size')) {
    add_image_size('270_250', 270, 250, true);
    add_image_size('170_158', 170, 158, true);
}
```

`true` указывает на жёсткое кадрирование. Конструкция `get_post_thumbnail_id(43, array(170, 158))` скорее всего вообще ошибочная, т. к. `get_post_thumbnail_id()` принимает всего один аргумент. Попробуйте так:

```
$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(43), '170_158');
```

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало.